# Getting list object is not callable error

Tags: python, list, callable

```
def simplify(intlist):
  nums = set(intlist)
  nums = bubblesort[intlist(nums)]
  simplified_list = []
```

Everytime I run my code I get a list object is not callable error for the 3rd line, why is this the case?

Comment: What is `intlist(nums)` supposed to do? Do you want to use `nums` to get the items at those indices out of `intlist`?

Answer (score 1):

`intlist(nums)` means "call the function `inlist` on argument `nums`", but `inlist` is not a function.

Maybe you mean `nums = bubblesort(list(nums))`

Comment: I don't think this solves the issue completely since now you're not using `intlist`. I think they want to use `nums` to get the items at those indices out of `intlist`.